# How do i display favicon.ico on blackberry devices?

Tags: blackberry, favicon, ico

I want to display the favicon.ico from websites on my blackberry application. I would normally use the EncodedImage class to convert the byte[] into a recognizable image file. However EncodedImage only supports PNG, BMP, JPG, TIFF, and GIF. Is there another method for me to display the ICO file on the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to use Google's supposedly undocumented favicon service that converts .ico to .png in a 16x16 format.

http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=blackberry.com will return blackberry's favicon as 16x16 png.

Answer (score 1):

You right. Encoded image don't support icon files.

You may try to find and/or port to J2ME one of open-source library.

Also you can try to create yourself realisation of EncodedImage.

And, in the end, you can use services like [convertico.com](http://www.convertico.com/) to convert .ico online or write yourself simple web-side script.